# Facebook Login opening different app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I have a friend who has installed my app on his iPhone. But when he tries to "login with Facebook app" from a different app(let's say 'Gaana'), it prompts him to open in my app. It's similar to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7536076?start=0&tstart=0). Has anyone else faced this issue? Does anyone know of a solution? Is it a bug in my app?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Can't tell if it's a bug in your app without see the code on how you processing the login.

Comment: Actually, fb login is implemented the same way as described in fb docs. Info.plist and others are good. FB login is working perfectly in my app. The code is just for login and logout. It shouldn't be interfering in someone else's app.

Comment: i have same issue